# What is the meaning of 'code vetting' in Software Engineering?

Tags: documentation, code-reviews, source-code

I saw the term **code vetting** for the first time in a [gerrit review page](https://review.opendev.org/Documentation/intro-quick.html). What does it mean?

The line I came across:

> "No **XYZ** check was done. However, if this project is intended to be
>   shipped in the future, please make sure **XYZ** Code Vetting is done."

Comment: Not much detail here - could you at least provide a source?

Comment: I don't think this is a term, it just means what it says

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vetting+meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### Definition of vet (Entry 3 of 3)
>
> *transitive verb*
>   1a : to evaluate for possible approval or acceptance
>   // *vet* the candidates for a position
>   b : to subject to usually expert appraisal or correction
>   // *vet* a manuscript

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vet))</sub>

You've tagged your question [code-reviews](/questions/tagged/code-reviews); well, 'code reviewing' seems like a good approximation to what that term means.